# Scraping information from Outlook email folder

Tags: python, email, parsing, outlook

Python newbie here...

I'm attempting to pull information from multiple emails within a folder in Outlook.

Everyday an email containing a table of information is sent to the mailbox and is autofiled into a folder. My aim is to pull the information from the table in these emails for the last 6 months and present this in a pandas dataframe.

I have no idea how to scrape this information from an email and would appreciate any help.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to automate Outlook to get the required information. To get all items for the last 6 months you need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)